# Default login credentials for Virtuoso Conductor

Tags: credentials, virtuoso, change-password

I've just finished installing Virtuoso's opensource package and I'm running the web gui called Conductor.

It requires a login, but I don't think there was anything about setting that up during install.

is there a default un / pass for this? if now, how do I set one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to their documentation, you can log in initially as:

```
username: dba
password: dba
```

Edit: i also found that there are two different default users setup:

> There are two system users of immediate importance:
>
> dba -- the relational data administrative account
>   dav --the WebDAV adminstrative account.
>
> By default each of these accounts has
>   its password set the same as its username. It is strongly advised that
>   you change these as soon as possible for obvious security reasons.

http://ods.openlinksw.com/wiki/main/Main/VOSUbuntuNotes#Using%20Virtuoso

Answer (score 0):

There are supposedly several default users set up, per [Section 3.1.1 Default Passwords](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/defpasschange/) of their documentation (dba, dav, vad, demo, soap, fori), but dba and dav are the critical ones to change.  *Note: I don't actually see the other users under the Ubuntu Xenial virtuoso package (version 6.1.6+repack-0ubuntu5)*

That page also has the `isql` syntax to change the password (only for the logged in user, ie, dba) on the command line:

> This can be changed using the Interactive SQL utility. When started without parameters, the ISQL tries to log on as dba with the default password. The SQL statement to change a user's password is:
>
> `set password <old password> <new password>`
>
> The password is an identifier, so take care to use proper quotation.